# How can I add the authorization header for Azure App Service API?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-webjobs

I'm trying do some Azure Web Job management (i.e. List, Run, Stop) from a web app and am having trouble finding an example of the Authorization header to use for Azure App Service API.

I'm attempting to follow the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listwebjobs)

Also, is this the recommended way of doing this or should I be using [Kudu API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API)?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the two documents you provided is right.

The Azure Resource Manager API is used for general-purpose operations that are not service specific, such as list and get. And it use [Azure Active Directory OAuth2 Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to authenticate.

While the KUDU API is using [Deployment credentials](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials) to authenticate.

> How can I add the authorization header for Azure App Service API?

You can use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/) to set up your authorization header for Azure App Service API as below:

For rest api, you can choose Bearer Token and send your token in it:

[image: ![enter image description here]

For Kudu api, you can choose Basic Auth and send your username and password as Deployment credentials said. Then it will automatically generate token.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That got me on the right path. After some difficulty getting the token I got it working with help from this [blog post](https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/azure-rest-apis-postman/)